# How to download MP4 file that plays through a video player using the curl command

Tags: video, curl, download, embedded-resource, mp4

the following page automatically plays an MP4 that I want to download on a video player: `

> http://www.stylelife.com/phase2xl/media/videoplay.php?content_filename=136433981.mp4

However, when I use the curl command, it doesn't download the mp4

```
curl -o video.mp4 http://www.stylelife.com/phase2xl/media/videoplay.php?content_filename=136433981.mp4
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  3615  100  3615    0     0  27704      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 60250
```

I've looked through the source code on the page and the relevant part totally confuses me. That is, I don't know where the MP4 file is located.

```
<a href="mp4:136433981.mp4%3FPolicy%3DeyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOlt7IlJlc291cmNlIjoiMTM2NDMzOTgxLm1wNCIsIkNvbmRpdGlvbiI6eyJJcEFkZHJlc3MiOnsiQVdTOlNvdXJjZUlwIjoiMjQuMjEyLjIyMy40NS8zMiJ9LCJEYXRlTGVzc1RoYW4iOnsiQVdTOkVwb2NoVGltZSI6MTM2OTExMzg4OX19fV19%26Signature%3DdGKzwPP4X2g57LRopT4Df2rSm-Ds29Eyi9RQA6lAUxBBzeW6zn7XVQkzFbUPM9MudnJIBGaYqNNwrwvk20oaEqQauFZU6DL6qbvFUE9GRLjhAa0M9KPyMQAVGWYMZSX1fx1WKxdlmAc1FEYHZG1dwuH9AQY6Zj0Xndw4WSGPqGE_%26Key-Pair-Id%3DAPKAJRM5JRJKF6J7YB3A"
   style="display:block;width:640px;height:360px;"
   id="player">

</a>

      <script language="JavaScript">

      flowplayer("player", "http://www.stylelife.com/academy/player/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.10.swf", {
      key: '#$c38c5304eed2df48aaa',
        clip: {
            autoPlay: true,
            autoBuffering: false,
            provider: 'rtmp'
        },
        plugins: {
          rtmp: {
            url: "http://www.stylelife.com/academy/player/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.11.swf",
            netConnectionUrl: 'rtmp://s2vyr5bshlkw52.cloudfront.net:1935/cfx/st'
          }, 
          controls: { 
            url: 'http://www.stylelife.com/academy/player/flowplayer.controls-3.2.10.swf',
            fullscreen: true
          }  
        }
      });
      </script>
```

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This file is being served from cloudfront. Unless you know the origin server of the content you will not be able to get the actual mp4 location. Also it should be available publicly or you must know the signed url to get it. If it is not your content, in all probability all that is intentional.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any other way of downloading the video?